# Is there any way to copy a file using a poweshell scipt to another directory?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm currently in the process of creating a Powershell script for the company I work at, but I ran into some problems when trying to copy a start.bin file from my USB stick where the script is located to the C:\ drive using this script I found:

```
# Copy the start.bin file into all existing profiles, to overwrite all the crap MS is including in the default Start Menu
# Won't prevent users from unpinning these items or pinning new items, only handles initial cleanup
echo ""
echo "Clean up new and existing Start Menu's"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Source = 'start.bin'
$Destination = 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}
Copy-Item -path start.bin -Destination C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState
```

i get the following error message:

```
Clean up new and existing Start Menu's
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState'.
At E:\--Custom--\src\startmenuw11.ps1:9 char:1
+ Copy-Item -path start.bin -Destination C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

it states that the C:\ directory cant be found on the USB stick "D:" which is obvious. is there any way to make the script go to the c drive?

I'm quite new to the whole scripting thing.

Comment: what is the source path and what the destination path? your current call ```Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}```makes no sense... but to your question: ```copy-item -path C:\start.bin  -Destination C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState```

Comment: You should rethink what `$Source` and `$Destination` mean.. You copy an item from its **source** path to a **destination** path, not the other way around. Also, check if path `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState` can be found and if it is accessible to you